# Using numpy.apply

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

What's wrong with this snippet of code?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

d = np.arange(10.0)
cutoffs = [stats.scoreatpercentile(d, pct) for pct in range(0, 100, 20)]
f = lambda x: np.sum(x > cutoffs)
fv = np.vectorize(f)

# why don't these two lines output the same values?
[f(x) for x in d] # => [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
fv(d)             # => array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cutoffs` is a list. The numbers you extract from `d` are all turned into `float` and applied using `numpy.vectorize`. (It's actually rather odd—it looks like first it tries numpy floats that work like you want then it tries normal Python floats.) By a rather odd, stupid behavior in Python, floats are always less than lists, so instead of getting things like

```
>>> # Here is a vectorized array operation, like you get from numpy. It won't
>>> # happen if you just use a float and a list.
>>> 2.0 > [0.0, 1.8, 3.6, 5.4, 7.2]
[True, True, False, False, False] # not real
```

you get

```
>>> # This is an actual copy-paste from a Python interpreter
>>> 2.0 > [0.0, 1.8, 3.6, 5.4, 7.2]
False
```

To solve the problem, you can make `cutoffs` a numpy array instead of a `list`. (You could probably also move the comparison into numpy operations entirely instead of faking it with `numpy.vectorize`, but I do not know offhand.)

Comment: "floats are always less than lists" is not obviously "stupid": how do you compare things that cannot be compared?  (like apples and ideas)

Comment: You don't, which is why this should raise an exception. (In 3.x, comparing a list and a float will raise `TypeError`, in realisation that Python shouldn't do things that make no sense.)